# PyBrain - Calculate based on input history

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

what to do if I need a model such that it will calculate the output based on the current inputs and the previous inputs:

[History of inputs, X and Y are used to calculate the future Z value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VYys.png)

I have done some coding, but I am not able to add this, any ideas how to make such change??

```
net = buildNetwork(numberofinputs, number_of_nodes, numberofoutputs, bias=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, learningrate=0.01,momentum=0.99)
print("Start training")
a = trainer.trainUntilConvergence(verbose=True,` dataset=ds,maxEpochs=10,continueEpochs=1000, validationProportion=0.99)
print("Finished training")
print(trainer.train())
```

This code is calculating the output based on the current inputs only, I want it to mesmerize the last 3 inputs values, and use with the current input to predict the next output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the previous input, then just add it as another feature. So if your current feature vector is

```
x_t = (x1_t, x2_t, x3_t)
```

and your next feature vector is

```
x_{t+1} = (x1_{t+1}, x2_{t+1}, x3_{t+1})
```

Then you can simply use

```
x_new = (x1_t, x2_t, x3_t, x1_{t+1}, x2_{t+1}, x3_{t+1})
```

as an input feature vector.

### Recurrent Neural Networks

However, if you need a time series of variable length as an input vector, you can use recurrent neural networks. I don't think PyBrain can do that. I suggest you have a look at [Google Tensor Flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). For a tutorial in RNNs, have a look at those two excellent blog posts:

- [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) by Andrej Karpathy
- [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) by Christopher Olah